# How to write text inside the bar in a horizontal bar graph matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, bar-chart

My code so far gives me something that looks like this:
[image]

I am wanting to write in the bars themselves if possible to get something like this:
[image]

Here's my base code so far:

**I'd like to put `Disease` into the bar**

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

x = [u'Rimegepant',u'Rimegepant',u'Zavegepant',u'Zavegepant',u'Troriluzole',u'Troriluzole',u'Troriluzole',u'Verdiperstat',u'Verdiperstat']

y = [4,3,3,3,2,3,3,3,3]

Disease = ['Acute Treatment of Migraine','Preventive Treatment of Migraine','Acute and Preventive Migraine','Lung Inflammation COVID-19',"Alzheimer's Disease", "OCD", "Spinocerebellar Ataxia", "Multiple System Atrophy", "Amyotrophic Lateral Sclerosis"]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()    
width = 0.75 # the width of the bars 
ind = np.arange(len(y))  # the x locations for the groups
ax.barh(ind, y, width, color="green", align='edge')
ax.set_yticks(ind+width/2)
ax.set_yticklabels(x, minor=False)
plt.xticks(np.arange(5),('Pre-clinical','Phase I','Phase II','Phase III', 'Approved'))
plt.margins(0,0.05)
plt.title('BHVN')
plt.ylabel('Drug')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add text to the ax via matplotlib as `ax.text()`.

If you add

```
for bar, disease in zip(ax.patches, Disease[::-1]):
    ax.text(0.1, bar.get_y()+bar.get_height()/2, disease, color = 'white', ha = 'left', va = 'center')
```

just before `plt.show()` in your code, you'll get:

[image]

Note, I had to reverse your `Disease` list (using [::-1]) for text to appear the way you have in your image, otherwise Amyotrophic Lateral Sclerosis is on top, and Acute Treatment of Migraine on the bottom.

Function generic form comes in `plt.text(x, y, text)`, so you see I offset x by 0.1 and get y from the bar patch.

For extra information on the function, you can check out [matplotlib documentation here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html)

Comment: Also something like this works for vertical bars to writing texts vertical, if anyone is looking for: `for each_bar in bars: plt.text(each_bar.get_x() + each_bar.get_width() / 2.0, 20, your_text_in_every_iteration, color='red', ha='center', va='center', rotation='vertical')` Before this you need to assign the plot to a variable like this: `bars = plt.bar(xlist, ylist)`

Answer (score 2):

This will work fine:

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = [u'Rimegepant',u'Rimegepant',u'Zavegepant',u'Zavegepant',u'Troriluzole',u'Troriluzole',u'Troriluzole',u'Verdiperstat',u'Verdiperstat']

y = [4,3,3,3,2,3,3,3,3]

Disease = ['Acute Treatment of Migraine','Preventive Treatment of Migraine','Acute and Preventive Migraine','Lung Inflammation COVID-19',"Alzheimer's Disease", "OCD", "Spinocerebellar Ataxia", "Multiple System Atrophy", "Amyotrophic Lateral Sclerosis"]
Disease.reverse()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
width = 0.75 # the width of the bars
ind = np.arange(len(y))  # the x locations for the groups
bar_plot = ax.barh(ind, y, width, color="green", align='edge')
ax.set_yticks(ind+width/2)
ax.set_yticklabels(x, minor=False)
plt.xticks(np.arange(5),('Pre-clinical','Phase I','Phase II','Phase III', 'Approved'))

def autolabel(bar_plot):
    for idx,rect in enumerate(bar_plot):
        ax.text(0.25, idx+.25, Disease[idx], color = 'white')
autolabel(bar_plot)

plt.margins(0,0.05)
plt.title('BHVN')
plt.ylabel('Drug')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x =[u'Rimegepant',u'Rimegepant',u'Zavegepant',u'Zavegepant',u'Troriluzole',u'Troriluzole',u'Troriluzole',u'Verdiperstat',u'Verdiperstat']

y = [4,3,3,3,2,3,3,3,3]

Disease = ['Acute Treatment of Migraine','Preventive Treatment of Migraine','Acute and Preventive Migraine','Lung Inflammation COVID-19',"Alzheimer's Disease", "OCD", "Spinocerebellar Ataxia", "Multiple System Atrophy", "Amyotrophic Lateral Sclerosis"]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
width = 0.75 # the width of the bars
ind = np.arange(len(y))  # the x locations for the groups

# I changed this line
p1 = ax.barh(ind,y, width, color="green", align='edge')
ax.set_yticks(ind+width/2)
ax.set_yticklabels(x, minor=False)

# I added this line
ax.bar_label(p1, Disease, label_type='center')
plt.xticks(np.arange(5),('Pre-clinical','Phase I','Phase II','Phase III', 'Approved'))
plt.margins(0,0.05)
plt.title('BHVN')
plt.ylabel('Drug')

plt.show()
```

You need to change the order of the disease list so it can show correctly