# Add two texts to each bar chart in plotly

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart

I am working on plotly (python) to plot a horizontal bar chart like the below figure.

```
import plotly.express as px


fig = px.bar(
         x=prices,
        y=['Average $' + str(round(avg_price, 2)), 'Lowest $' + 
str(round(min_price, 2)), 'Last $' + str(round(last_price, 2)), 
'Proposed $' + str(round(proposed_price, 2))],
         color=['Last', 'Average', 'Lowest',  'Proposed'],
         text=delta,
         orientation='h',
         height=400,
        )
fig.add_vline(x=spend[-1], line_width=2, line_dash="dash", 
line_color="red")
fig.add_vline(x=max(spend), line_width=2, line_dash="dash", 
line_color="green")
fig.update_traces( textposition='outside')


fig.update_layout(
        title="Saving/Loss diagram",
        xaxis_title="",
        yaxis_title="",
        legend_title="Vendor names",
        width=1000,
        )
fig.show()
```

[image]

In this figure I display text only outside of each bar chart. But now I am going to display another text inside each bar chart. How can I do that in plotly (python)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837165/16310106

Comment: trythis:`fig.update_traces( textposition='inside')`

Comment: @Hamzawi, thanks for the comment, but actually no, because that post is related to `matplotlib` library but my question is about `plotly` library.

Comment: @r-beginners, If I  write `fig.update_traces( textposition='inside')` in my code then it will display same thing (the numbers) inside of each chart. But I want to display totally different  text inside of each chart.

Comment: I didn't understand it well enough. To add a new one, use add_annotation(). For example, you can write `fig.add_annotation(text="text", xref="domain", yref="domain", x=180, y=1, showarrow=False)`

Comment: @r-beginners, yeah, thanks for the comment, this is the solution for my problem. Based on your suggestion I solved my problem, thanks a lot)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a text inside the bars with `plotly.express`, you could use `fig.update_traces` with two parameters `texttemplate` and `textposition`

You could try this code:

```
import plotly.express as px

data_canada = px.data.gapminder().query("country == 'Canada'")
fig = px.bar(data_canada, x='year', y='pop')
fig.update_traces(texttemplate = data_canada.year.unique(),textposition = "inside")
fig.show()
```

[image]

There is an option to do all this with `plotly.graph_objects`.

But here, you should add `text` that appears inside the bars and `textposition` adjust the text.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

data_canada = px.data.gapminder().query("country == 'Canada'")

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Bar(
            x=data_canada.year, y=data_canada["pop"],
            text=data_canada.year.unique(),
            textposition='inside'
        )])

fig.show()
```

[image]

**Update based on the comments:**

You can change the position of each text for each bar but the possible positions are four positions: "inside" | "outside" | "auto" | "none" as documented on the main page of plotly [here](https://plotly.com/python/reference/bar/#bar-textposition), search for textposition attribute.

To do this you can do it as follows:

```
import plotly.express as px
x = ['Aaron', 'Bob', 'Chris','Tom','Anna']
y = [5, 10, 6, 11, 8]

texts = ["first","second","third","fourth","fifth"]
positions = ['inside','outside','auto','outside','inside']
fig = px.bar(x=x, y=y)
fig.update_traces(texttemplate = texts, textposition = positions)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, yeah I got what you mean, but in my case it was a bit different. May be my explanation wasn't good enough. My aim was to add two different texts to each cell with different positions at the same time. I appreciate you for the response. It is very useful.

Comment: Yes, the last update was not in your question. You would have saved a lot of time. Your goal is to add two different texts in each bar with two different positions at the same time? I hope to make your question clearer by writing your desired output on the image.

Comment: I am very sorry for the late response. Yes really did very nice work, thanks for such a detail and clear explanation. But in my case I wanted to add two texts to each bar at same time. For example for the chart `Aaron` you put the text `first` inside of the text and I also wanted to add another text to the outside of that bar. I hope my idea is clear. Maybe my explanation wans't good enough(sorry), I actually did the task. If you interested I can share my solution with you.