# Fully display the amount in horizontal bar chart

Tags: python, plotly

With `fig.update_traces(textposition="outside", textangle=0 )`, chart plus text over the background will not able to fully display.

With `fig.update_traces(textposition="inside", textangle=0 )`, chart too short will not fully display the text amount as well.

So, is there any way to make it win-win situation?

```
fig = px.bar(pie_bar_gp, x='Amount', y='Product', title='Pie-Bar' ,orientation='h' 
                ,text='Amount', text_auto=",.2f"
                )      
    

    fig.update_layout(barmode="group")
    fig.update_layout({
          'paper_bgcolor': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
        })
```

chart with:

```
    fig.update_traces(textposition="inside", textangle=0 )
```

[image: ![image|690x188](upload://itwN8pXp4HPSycsibR7ZPvwgKct.png)]

```
 fig.update_traces(textposition="outside", textangle=0 )
```

[image: ![image|690x197](upload://cIcIYzOI9rI0Ydaa8vEopiE23M.png)]

Comment: The answer is easy, you can increase the width of the plot while the position is outside.

Comment: or increase the figuresize(12,12) or something bigger than this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases, you can pass a list of the positions you wish to display for each value. The example in the [reference](https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/#bar-chart-with-plotly-express) is forced to limit the range of the x-axis, creating the same situation as your assignment. I have set my threshold as 25, anything below that is outside and everything else is inside.

```
import plotly.express as px

data_Rwanda = px.data.gapminder().query("country == 'Rwanda'")
txt_position = ['outside' if x <= 25 else 'inside' for x in data_canada['lifeExp']]

fig = px.bar(data_Rwanda, x='lifeExp', y='year', orientation='h',text='lifeExp',text_auto=',.2f')

fig.update_xaxes(range=[23,50])
fig.update_traces(textposition=txt_position, textfont=dict(color='red', size=14))
fig.update_layout(autosize=True, height=600)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: what is the `barmode` in your graph? Is `stack` or `group`? As if the `barmode=group` , there is not issue with the custom textposition, but not function if the `barmode=stack`.

Comment: If bar mode is not specified, the default is `relative`. Text position is only valid for uniform settings in `barmode='stack'`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this if you provide a list of text positions for each bar.

```
positions = ['inside','inside','inside','outside','inside', 'inside'] 
fig = px.bar(pie_bar_gp, x='Amount', y='Product', 
  title='Pie-Bar', orientation='h', text='Amount', text_auto=",.2f")

fig.update_traces(textposition=positions) 
fig.show()
```

See the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68337253/10487273